# I want to delete my list item corresponding the date and time?

Tags: list, powershell

I have stack list now i want delete my list item corresponding the date and time.what are all the ways to delete list item. I used power-shell for particular list

```
$web = get-spweb -Identity http://sitename
$list = $web.lists["list name"]
$list.AllowDeletion = $true
$list.Update()
$list.Delete()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete a list item then first you need to get the corresponding item. For that you can use CAML query and pass the date time parameter

```
$list = $rootWeb.Lists.TryGetList($ListName);
$isoDeleteItemsDate = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPUtility]::CreateISO8601DateTimeFromSystemDateTime([DateTime]::Now); #change it to date of your preference

$camlQueryString = [String]::Format("<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='DateTimeFieldName' /><Value IncludeTimeValue='TRUE' Type='DateTime'>{0}</Value></Leq></Where>", $isoDeleteItemsDate);
$camlQuery = New-Object -TypeName "Microsoft.SharePoint.SPQuery" -ArgumentList @($list.DefaultView);
$camlQuery.Query=$camlQueryString;

$camlResults = [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItemCollection] $list.GetItems($camlQuery);
$listItems = [System.Data.DataTable]$camlResults.GetDataTable();
foreach($listItemRow in $listItems.Rows)
{
    $listItemIdToDelete = $listItemRow["ID"];
    $listItemToDelete = $listToProcess.GetItemById($listItemIdToDelete);
    $listItemToDelete.Delete();
}
```